# Shared python generator

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

I am trying to reproduce the reactive extensions "shared" observable concept with Python generators.

Say I have an API that gives me an infinite stream that I can use like this:

```py
def my_generator():
    for elem in the_infinite_stream():
        yield elem
```

I could use this generator multiple times like so:

```
stream1 = my_generator()
stream2 = my_generator()
```

And `the_infinite_stream()` will be called twice (once for each generator).

Now say that `the_infinite_stream()` is an expensive operation. Is there a way to "share" the generator between multiple clients? It seems like [tee](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) would do that, but I have to know in advance how many independent generators I want.

The idea is that in other languages (Java, Swift) using the reactive extensions (RxJava, RxSwift) "shared" streams, I can conveniently duplicate the stream on the client side. I am wondering how to do that in Python.

Note: I am using asyncio

Comment: By "share", do you mean to cache the values for use in the next generator?

Comment: Also, are these "real" streams (with .seek, .close, etc), or just general iterables? And would `stream1`, `stream2`, etc. be used in parallel, or only one-after-the-other?

Comment: You need to store the whole stream between the first and the last consumer - which becomes apparent if there is one consumer polling the infinite stream all the time, and one consumer lagging. And if you want any new consumer to start at the beginning, you need to cache it all. If that's okay with you, it's easy to implement.

Comment: If you don't want to replay the whole history to the new consumer, you're rather looking for some pub-sub scheme.

Comment: By "share", I mean the pub-sub scheme suggested by liborm: if an event A arrives from `infinite_stream()`, I want all the subscribers to receive it. I don't want to replay the whole history, but just the last value (say `infinite_stream()` emits once per minute, when a subscriber joins, he doesn't want to wait 1 minute to receive the first value).

Comment: This is really "built in" reactive extensions, and I am wondering if such a mechanism exists in python (possibly in asyncio). Implementing it myself does not sound super straightforward and that's prone to error, therefore I'd rather use something standard (just like I use RxJava or RxSwift) =).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I took `tee` implementation and modified it such you can have various number of generators from `infinite_stream`:

```
import collections

def generators_factory(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    deques = []
    already_gone = []

    def new_generator():
        new_deque = collections.deque()
        new_deque.extend(already_gone)
        deques.append(new_deque)

        def gen(mydeque):
            while True:
                if not mydeque:             # when the local deque is empty
                    newval = next(it)       # fetch a new value and
                    already_gone.append(newval)
                    for d in deques:        # load it to all the deques
                        d.append(newval)
                yield mydeque.popleft()

        return gen(new_deque)

    return new_generator

# test it:
infinite_stream = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
factory = generators_factory(infinite_stream)
gen1 = factory()
gen2 = factory()
print(next(gen1)) # 1
print(next(gen2)) # 1 even after it was produced by gen1
print(list(gen1)) # [2, 3, 4, 5] # the rest after 1
```

To cache only some amount of values you can change `already_gone = []` into `already_gone = collections.deque(maxlen=size)` and add `size=None` parameter to `generators_factory`.

Comment: That's interesting. And it could be extended such that `already_gone` has a `max_size` (say, 1), so that it caches only one value. Correct?

Comment: Does it mean that if `gen1` and `gen2` are used in parallel, the order may not be respected? Mainly out of curiosity... I am trying (currently failing) to port that to asyncio and it may be different there.

Comment: Order of produced elements? Nor for tee neither for my implementation.

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask new question about your asyncio failed attempts with a reference to this one.

Comment: Good to know for tee! I got something working with asyncio, I still need to figure out how to remove consumers that would cancel their subscription. It may end up on codereview once I get it to work!

Answer (score 3):

Consider simple [class attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923579/python-class-attribute).

**Given**

```
def infinite_stream():
    """Yield a number from a (semi-)infinite iterator."""
    # Alternatively, `yield from itertools.count()`
    yield from iter(range(100000000))


# Helper
def get_data(iterable):
    """Print the state of `data` per stream."""
    return ", ".join([f"{x.__name__}: {x.data}" for x in iterable])
```

**Code**

```
class SharedIterator:
    """Share the state of an iterator with subclasses."""
    _gen = infinite_stream()
    data = None

    @staticmethod
    def modify():
        """Advance the shared iterator + assign new data."""
        cls = SharedIterator
        cls.data = next(cls._gen)
```

**Demo**

Given a tuple of client `streams` (`A`, `B` and `C`),

```
# Streams
class A(SharedIterator): pass
class B(SharedIterator): pass
class C(SharedIterator): pass


streams = A, B, C
```

let us modify and print the state of one iterator shared between them:

```
# Observe changed state in subclasses    
A.modify()
print("1st access:", get_data(streams))
B.modify()
print("2nd access:", get_data(streams))
C.modify()
print("3rd access:", get_data(streams))
```

Output

```
1st access: A: 0, B: 0, C: 0
2nd access: A: 1, B: 1, C: 1
3rd access: A: 2, B: 2, C: 2
```

Although any stream can modify the iterator, the class attribute is shared between sub-classes.

**See Also**

- [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) on `asyncio.Queue` - an async alternative to shared container
- [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065579/chaining-coroutines-in-asyncio-and-observer-pattern) on the Observer Pattern + `asyncio`

Comment: But then it seems to me that when A consumes (`modify()`) an event, it is consumed for B and C at the same time. So if I do `next(A); next(B); next(C);` they don't all get the same event, do they?

Comment: I believe that Sanyash answer does exactly what I want. But your solution doesn't behave the same way, does it? Maybe I miss something there =/.

Comment: That's correct according to your comment "if an event A arrives from `infinite_stream()`, I want all the subscribers to receive it." This may be another interpretation of what you actually want.

Answer (score 3):

You can call "tee" repeatedly to create multiple iterators as needed.

```py
it  = iter([ random.random() for i in range(100)])
base, it_cp = itertools.tee(it)
_, it_cp2 = itertools.tee(base)
_, it_cp3 = itertools.tee(base)
```

Sample: http://tpcg.io/ZGc6l5.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to regenerate base. `_, it_cp2 = itertools.tee(base)` works just as well after the first time it is created.

Comment: I should have and have edited it now.  Last night I couldn't figure out why this worked and thought I might need to delete the comment.  This morning I took a look at the C code - and when you call tee with N > 1 I think this is effectively what it is doing.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize I could call `tee` repeatedly. However, that is caching all the events of the infinite stream, isn't it? I haven't found a way to set a `max_size` in `tee` (which is possibly why @Sanyash reimplemented it?).

Comment: Based on the C code I think it caches only the items where at least 1 iterator still needs the data. 

So yes in the answer above it will cache all of them.  On the other hand if instead of basing them all on `base` you tee off an iterator that has already been moved it will cache from that point onwards, but doesn't have the flexibility of @Sanyash to solution look backwards an X (or unlimited) element cache.

Answer (score 3):

You can use single generator and "subscriber generators":

```py
subscribed_generators = []


def my_generator():
    while true:
        elem = yield
        do_something(elem) # or yield do_something(elem) depending on your actual use

def publishing_generator():
    for elem in the_infinite_stream():
        for generator in subscribed_generators:
            generator.send(elem)

subscribed_generators.extend([my_generator(), my_generator()])

# Next is just ane example that forces iteration over `the_infinite_stream`
for elem in publishing_generator():
    pass
```

Instead of generator-function you may also create a class with methods: `__next__`, `__iter__`, `send`, `throw`. That way you can modify `MyGenerator.__init__` method to automatically add new instances of it to `subscribed_generators`.

This is somewhat similar to event-based approach with a "dumb implementation":

- `for elem in the_infinite_stream` is similar to emitting event
- `for generator ...: generator.send` is similar to sending event to each subscriber.

So one way to implement a "more complex but structured solution" would be to use event-based approach:

- For example you can use [asyncio.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event)
- Or some third-party solution like [aiopubsub](https://github.com/qntln/aiopubsub)
- For any of those approaches you should emit event for each element from `the_infinite_stream`, and your instances of `my_generator` should be subscribed to those events.

And other approaches can also be used and the best choice depends: on details of your task, on how are you using event-loop in asyncio. For example:

- You can implement `the_infinite_stream` (or wrapper for it) as some class with "cursors" (objects that track current position in the stream for different subscribers); then each `my_generator` registers new cursor and uses it to get next item in the infinite stream. In this approach event-loop will not automatically revisit `my_generator` instances, which might be required if those instances "are not equal" (for example have some "priority balancing")
- Intermediate generator calling all the instances of `my_generator` (as described earlier). In this approach each instance of `my_generator` is automatically revisited by event-loop. Most likely this approach is thread-safe.
- Event-based approaches:

  - using `asyncio.Event`. Similar to use of intermediate generator. Not
    thread-safe
  - aiopubsub.
  - something that uses [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
- Make `the_infinite_generator` (or wrapper for it) to be "Singleton" that "caches" latest event. Some approaches were described in other answers. Another "caching" solutions can be used:

  - emit the same element once for each instance of `the_infinite_generator` (use class with custom `__new__` method that tracks instances, or use the same instance of class that has a method returning "shifted" iterator over `the_infinite_loop`) until someone calls special method on
    instance of `the_infinite_generator` (or on class): `infinite_gen.next_cycle`. In
    this case there should always be some "last finalizing
    generator/processor" that at the end of each event-loop's cycle will
    do `the_infinite_generator().next_cycle()`
  - Similar to previous but same event is allowed to fire multiple times in the same `my_generator` instance (so they should watch for this case). In this approach `the_infinite_generator().next_cycle()` can be called "periodically" with [loop.call_later or loop.cal_at](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#scheduling-delayed-callbacks). This approach might be needed if "subscribers" should be able to handle/analyze: delays, rate-limits, timeouts between events, etc.
- Many other solutions are possible. It's hard to propose something specific without looking at your current implementation and without knowing what is the desired behavior of generators that use `the_infinite_loop`

If I understand your description of "shared" streams correctly, that you really need "one" `the_infinite_stream` generator and a "handler" for it. Example that tries to do this:

```py
class StreamHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__real_stream = the_infinite_stream()
        self.__sub_streams = []

    def get_stream(self):
        sub_stream = []  # or better use some Queue/deque object. Using list just to show base principle
        self.__sub_streams.append(sub_stream)
        while True:
            while sub_stream:
                yield sub_stream.pop(0)
            next(self)

    def __next__(self):
        next_item = next(self.__real_stream)
        for sub_stream in self.__sub_steams:
            sub_stream.append(next_item)

some_global_variable = StreamHandler()
# Or you can change StreamHandler.__new__ to make it singleton, or you can create an instance at the point of creation of event-loop

def my_generator():
    for elem in some_global_variable.get_stream():
        yield elem
```

But if all your `my_generator` objects are initialized at the same point of infinite stream, and "equally" iterated inside the loop, then this approach will introduce "unnecessary" memory overhead for each "sub_stream" (used as queue). Unnecessary: because those queues will always be the same (but that can be optimized: if there are some existing "empty" sub_stream than it can be re-used for new sub_streams with some changes to "`pop`-logic"). And many-many other implementations and nuances can be discussed

Comment: I see. So a consumer of that stream can implement its own `my_generator()` and has to append it manually to `subscribed_generators`, right? But then I don't get what the last `for` does :/

Comment: @JonesV: You always have some "upper code" that creates those `my_generator()` calls: you can append it there. You are not restricted to to some global variable of `subscribed_generators`, the code just "explains a concept", and many other approaches are possible. See my answer: I've updated it with more details and with a list of some other potential approaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration! I went for Sanyash implementation in my code, that I could quite easily adapt for asyncio, hence I validate that answer. However, the thoughts here are super nice, and I did not know `aiopubsub`, which seems very nice!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single generator, you can use one queue per "subscriber" and route events to each subscriber as the primary generator produces results.

This has the advantage of allowing the subscribers to move at their own pace, and it can be dropped in existing code with very little changes to the original source.

For example:

```
def my_gen():
  ...

m1 = Muxer(my_gen)
m2 = Muxer(my_gen)

consumer1(m1).start()
consumer2(m2).start()
```

As items are pulled from the primary generator they are inserted into queues for each listener.   Listeners can subscribe any time by constructing a new Muxer():

```
import queue
from threading import Lock
from collections import namedtuple

class Muxer():
    Entry = namedtuple('Entry', 'genref listeners, lock')

    already = {}
    top_lock = Lock()

    def __init__(self, func, restart=False):
        self.restart = restart
        self.func = func
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

        with self.top_lock:
            if func not in self.already:
                self.already[func] = self.Entry([func()], [], Lock())
            ent = self.already[func]

        self.genref = ent.genref
        self.lock = ent.lock
        self.listeners = ent.listeners

        self.listeners.append(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            e = self.queue.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:
            with self.lock:
                try:
                    e = self.queue.get_nowait()
                except queue.Empty:
                    try:
                        e = next(self.genref[0])
                        for other in self.listeners:
                            if not other is self:
                                other.queue.put(e)
                    except StopIteration:
                        if self.restart:
                            self.genref[0] = self.func()
                        raise
        return e
```

Original source code, including test suite:

https://gist.github.com/earonesty/cafa4626a2def6766acf5098331157b3

The unit tests run many threads concurrently processing the same generated events in sequence.   The code is order preserving, with a lock acquired during the single generator's access.

Caveats: the version here uses a singleton to gate access, otherwise it would be possible to accidentally evade its control over the contained generators.   It also allows the contained generators to be "restartable", which was a useful feature for me a the time.   There is no "close()" feature, simply because I didn't need it.   This is an appropriate use case for `__del__` however, since the last reference to a listener is the right time to clean up.